# Question on basic probability from Maths In Focus textbook

Tags: probability

A set of cards is numbered 1 to 20 and three are selected. Find the probability of selecting
a) all three 10's
b) no 10's
c) at least one 10.

I have solved part a) by stating that 
P(one 10)= 1/20, and therefore 
P(3 10's)= (1/20 x 1/20 x 1/20)
= 1/8000

To approach a question like b), I would usually draw a tree diagram and add all the possible results that give the desired outcome (I.e. No 10's). However, this  would take an extremely long time to do. Is there a more efficient way to solve b)?

Also, I understand that the answer to b) is required to answer c), which would be solved by showing that 
P( at least one 10) = 1- P(No 10's)

Thank you.

Comment: I assume that the cards drawn with replacement? If so, the answer to (b) is $(\frac{19}{20})^3$ as a non-ten needs to be obtained on all three draws. Your method of calculating (c) from (b) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

a) is correct.

b) No 10s is equivalent to picking one of the other 19 cards. The probability of this once is $\frac{19}{20}$, and the answer is $\left( \frac{19}{20} \right)^3$

c) As you pointed out, the answer is 1 - b)

To figure out if you've understood what's happening, try doing part b) if the cards are drawn without replacement - i.e. if the first draw was 4, then 4 cannot be drawn again.